# I cannot style a traditional html form drop down menu which is filled by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this drop down menu which is filled by JavaScript. I want to style the elements in the drop down but somehow nothing I tried worked. Does anyone have suggestions?

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="cddp">

<select name='List1' onchange="fillSelect(this.value,this.form['List2'])">
<option selected>Category</option>
</select>

&nbsp;
<select name='List2' onchange="getValue(this.value,this.form['List1'].value)">
<option selected >Subcategory</option>
</select>
</div>
```

The CSS for it:

```
.cddp{
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically specify the select element in your CSS selector, so for your example:

```
.cddp select {
    color: red;
}
```

to select any `SELECT` elements (directly) inside cddp class elements. Or move the class to the `SELECT` elements.

Answer (score 4):

Here I have share a simple Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.cddp{
    color: red;
}
.cddp select{
    color: green;
}
</style>
<script>
function favBrowser()
{
var mylist=document.getElementById("myList");
document.getElementById("favorite").value=mylist.options[mylist.selectedIndex].text;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
<div class="cddp">
Select your favorite browser:
<select id="myList" onchange="favBrowser()">
  <option></option>
  <option>Google Chrome</option>
  <option>Firefox</option>  
  <option>Internet Explorer</option>
  <option>Safari</option>
  <option>Opera</option>
</select>
</div>
<p>Your favorite browser is: <input type="text" id="favorite" size="20"></p>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

`.cddp` will match the parent `div` of your `select` elements. You want to target `select` elements inside this `.cddp` div instead. You can use space to target descendants of an element:

```
.cddp select {
    color: red;
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aEJE7/)**